# UIScrollView's delegate methods not firing

Tags: ios, delegates, uiscrollviewdelegate

I can't get the viewDidScroll method to fire in my custom class... I know, I know this has been in multiple stackoverflow posts... I have read dozens... Please help!

Following directions from other S.O. posts,

I have added the protocol in my .h file:

```
@interface ISCByStyleView : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

I have declared a "delegate" property in the .h file of this custom class:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id delegate;
```

I have referenced the delegate in the .m file like this:

```
self.delegate=self;
```

But when I scroll the Scroll View, the method viewDidSCroll WILL NOT fire.

Here is the .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FMDatabase.h"
#import "FMResultSet.h"
#import "ISCAppDelegate.h"

@interface ISCByStyleView : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) id delegate;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *iboStylesView;

@end
```

And here are the important parts of the .m

```
#import "ISCByStyleView.h"
#import "ISCTableView.h"

@interface ISCByStyleView ()

@property NSNumber *selectedStyle;
@property NSNumber *selectedQuery;
@property NSTimer *ssTimer;

@end

@implementation ISCByStyleView

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.delegate=self;

...

- (void) resetTimer {
    [self.ssTimer invalidate];
    self.ssTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30 target:self  selector:@selector(launchScreenSaver) userInfo:Nil repeats:NO];
NSLog (@"Timer Reset");
}

//Reset with Scrolling
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
NSLog (@"ByStyleView: scrollDidScroll event");
    [self resetTimer];

}
```

Comment: Self.delegate=self is highly unlikely to be what you want. Show all the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ISCByStyleView` is a `UIViewController` and so you don't want to set self's delegate. Instead, you need to set your `UIScrollView`'s delegate to self, ex:

```
self.scrollview.delegate = self;
```

And declaring the `delegate` property in your `.h` using this line: `@property (nonatomic, strong) id delegate;` is unnecessary.

**Edit**: You could also set your `UIScrollView`'s delegate entirely within the Interface Builder if that's where you've created it like so:

**Step #1:**

[image]

**Step #2:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you Lindsey. I have added more code above. My Scroll View is created with IB and does not have a name. Shall I name the Scroll View with an IB Outlet? (Trying to avoid creating Scroll View programmatically). If I use self.iboStylesView.delegate = self;  (the view which does have a name), I get an error that "Property 'delegate' not found on type UIView. -Steve

Comment: @user3369429 You can either create an IBOutlet or set the delegate within your interface... I'll post a screen shot in a sec to show you how...

Comment: OhMyGosh. A control-drag in storyboard created the delegate that I have been struggling to create programmatically for days. I hope this post comes up in future searches. THANK YOU LYNDSEY!

Comment: @user3369429 No problem. :) I'll update your title a little bit to make it a little more search friendly.